# Jest - How to find rendered DOM component with id?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am writing a simple Jest test that verifies that my component rendered. I see that React's TestUtils has functions for finding rendered components by class or by tag, but not by their ID attribute. There is a [`findAllInRenderedTree`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#findallinrenderedtree) function, but the documentation does not explain what the callback should expect.

I would guess that the callback will receive some sort of element object, which is not a normal DOM element or an ordinary React component. What exactly is passed to `findAllInRenderedTree`'s callback, and how am I supposed to get its attributes, or at least its ID?

I would just `console.log` the callback's arguments, but I am having a hard time getting console  to work in a Jest test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The callback argument of `findAllInRenderedTree` gets passed a component instance and should return a boolean that indicates whether the component should be kept in the output array.

In your case, to find all rendered DOM components with a given id:

```js
function scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithId(tree, id) {
  return TestUtils.findAllInRenderedTree(tree, function(inst) {
    return TestUtils.isDOMComponent(inst) && inst.getAttribute("id") === id;
  });
}
```

If you need to test against attributes of the actual DOM Node, you can use `React.findDOMNode(inst)` to retrieve the DOM Node of a given component instance.

Comment: Reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246645/how-to-check-props-of-a-dom-node-in-an-unit-test-in-react-0-14, the way do it from now on should be: `return isDOMComponent(inst) && inst.getAttribute('id') === id;`