# How to check props of a DOM node in an unit test in React 0.14?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

After upgrading React from `0.13` to `v0.14.0-beta3`, I got a lot of warnings like this in my unit tests:

```
Warning: ReactDOMComponent: Do not access .props of a DOM node; instead, recreate the props as `render` did originally or read the DOM properties/attributes directly from this node (e.g., this.refs.box.className). This DOM node was rendered by `Button`.
```

They are caused by my unit tests, for example:

```
it('should render to a <a> when href is given', function () {
    var button = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Button className="amazon" href="#">Hello</Button>);
    expect(TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(button, 'button').length).toBe(0);
    expect(TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(button, 'a').length).toBe(1);
    expect(TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(button, 'a')[0].props.href).toBe('#');
    expect(TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(button, 'a')[0].props.className).toBe('amazon Button');
});
```

How do I fix this? Is there any recommended practice for testing DOM elements like this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to test the value of the props like this, as you know exactly what you're passing.  The component itself cannot change the value of the props so props will always be what you give it.

Comment: I'm checking the props of a child node (so not the ones I just passed), so this does make sense.

Answer (score 17):

In the debugger I discovered that these elements (like, in my case, `TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(button, 'a')[0]`) are in fact DOM elements with just some React properties added (like `props` and `state`).

[image: debugger]

So now, with this knowledge, I can write my assertions based on DOM attributes and properties, like:

```
expect(b.getAttribute('href')).toEqual('#');
```

Comment: .props, etc. on DOM nodes exist as a migration aid only and will be removed in 0.15.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Do you have an alternative solution then?

Comment: No, your solution is correct! I'm just saying that they won't have the added React properties in a future version – that's why you get a warning when using those properties now.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the warning just call a prop directly. 
For example:

warning code:

```
this.refs.input.props.name
```

fixed code:

```
this.refs.input.name
```