# How to test child props without triggering "Do not access .props of a DOM node" (0.14)?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, tdd

I have a component whose job it is to add certain properties to its child:

```
const Parent = React.createClass({
  doStuff() {
    // ...
  },

  render() {
    const child = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {doStuff: this.doStuff});
    return <div>{child}</div>;
  }
});
```

With 0.13 I could test it like this:

```
const {renderIntoDocument, findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass} = TestUtils;

const parent = renderIntoDocument(<Parent><span className="test" /></Parent>);
const child = findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(parent, "test");

expect(child.props.doStuff).to.equal(parent.doStuff);
```

What is the "0.14 way" of testing this?

PS. I test the behavior of Parent.doStuff elsewhere, but I also need to ensure that the given child gets a reference to this method.

PPS. I read [How to check props of a DOM node in an unit test in React 0.14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246645/how-to-check-props-of-a-dom-node-in-an-unit-test-in-react-0-14) but it does not apply to my problem because I'm not testing props that I could read with `domNode.getAttribute()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. Here is what now works for me (`Parent` is the unit under test):

```
const TestChild = () => <div />;

const TestContainer = React.createClass({
  getParent() {
    return this.refs.parent;
  },

  getChild() {
    return this.refs.testChild;
  },

  render() {
    return <Parent ref="parent"><TestChild ref="testChild" /></Parent>;
  }
});

const {renderIntoDocument, findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass} = TestUtils;

const testContainer = renderIntoDocument(<TestContainer />);
const parent = testContainer.getParent();
const child = testContainer.getChild();

expect(child.props.doStuff).to.equal(parent.doStuff);
```

`TestChild` has to be a custom component, otherwise `this.refs.testChild` only returns a DOM node instead of a component instance.