# Proper way to get input value while testing react elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js

In testing my react components with mocha, I'm receiving the warning:

> Warning: ReactDOMComponent: Do not access .props of a DOM node;
>   instead, recreate the props as `render` did originally or read the DOM
>   properties/attributes directly from this node (e.g.,
>   this.refs.box.className). This DOM node was rendered by `Input`.

My test looks like this:

```
const component = renderIntoDocument(ComponentA);
const inputs = scryRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(component, 'input');
expect(inputs[0].props.value).to.equal('abc123');
```

This works and the tests pass, but obviously I'm doing something wrong per the warning.  My question is **what is the proper way to test an input value in a component**

Note: The value is derived from a prop on the component e.g.`<ComponentA myName="abc"/>`

Comment: [Possible duplicate.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246645/how-to-check-props-of-a-dom-node-in-an-unit-test-in-react-0-14)